# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 on NEW box

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have looked at different solutions but nothing helped. Basically, i have a Kentico solution that came with MVC 3. I removed all the references and added MVC 5 via nuget. This works on the old test server since that has MVC 4 installed in it. We have deployed a new test web sever and this doesn't have MVC installed on it and we don't need it if DLLs are available in the bin folder. Now when i try to run the site on the new server, i get the following exception.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 


Line 1032:        {
Line 1033:            // Rewrite URL
Line 1034:            status = URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(relativePath, excludedEnum, siteName, viewMode);
Line 1035:        }
Line 1036:

Source File: e:\inetpub\KenticoCMS\App_Code\Application\CMSAppBase.cs    Line: 1034 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.ProcessPageTemplate(PageInfo pageInfo, RequestContext requestContext, IHttpHandler& handler, URLRewritingResultEnum& status) +0
   CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(String relativePath, ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum, SiteNameOnDemand siteName, ViewModeOnDemand viewMode) +10002
   CMSAppBase.RewriteUrl(URLRewritingResultEnum status, String relativePath, ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum, ViewModeOnDemand viewMode, SiteNameOnDemand siteName) in e:\inetpub\KenticoCMS\App_Code\Application\CMSAppBase.cs:1034
   CMSAppBase.CMSMapRequestHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\inetpub\KenticoCMS\App_Code\Application\CMSAppBase.cs:584
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

I am confused as to why it is looking for MVC 3 when in my bin folder i have the MVC 5 DLL available.

Web.Config

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false" validateRequest="false" clientIDMode="AutoID" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <add tagPrefix="cms" namespace="CMS.Controls" assembly="CMS.Controls" />
        <add tagPrefix="cms" namespace="CMS.FormEngine" assembly="CMS.FormEngine" />
        <add tagPrefix="cms" namespace="CMS.FormControls" assembly="CMS.FormControls" />
        <add tagPrefix="cms" namespace="CMS.ExtendedControls" assembly="CMS.ExtendedControls" />
        <add tagPrefix="cms" namespace="CMS.PortalControls" assembly="CMS.PortalControls" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions" />
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="CMS.CMSHelper" />
        <add namespace="CMS.GlobalHelper" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

 <compilation debug="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="100" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>


        <add assembly="SMDiagnostics, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Deployment, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Messaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.IdentityModel.Selectors, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

        <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />


      </assemblies>

    </compilation>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
  </system.web>


<runtime xmlns="">
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" publicKeyToken="1b03e6acf1164f73" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.85.3.365" newVersion="0.85.3.365" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.IO" publicKeyToken="834b12a258f213f9" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.5270.7138" newVersion="7.0.5270.7138" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

[image: Packages and Bin folder]

What reference am i missing here? The only thing that is coming to my mind is that i am missing some dependent assembly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a reference in a different project or config. Search for 3.0.0 see what comes up. NuGet package installs can be tricky. You know something is looking for it, you need to let it know you've upgraded.

Comment: I have searched once again and nothing is turning up with respect to MVC 3. I only have Kentico website in this solution.

Comment: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Upgrading+the+MVC+version maybe this will help?

Comment: This is for version 8. We are using version 7. I had conversation with the support and looks like i'll need to downgrade the project to MVC 3. Our other option was to install MVC 3 on our NEW servers and that we don't want to do.